# Testing Used Memory - MemTest86 Not Working?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, memtest

I recently purchased 4x 1GB sticks of PC2-6400U RAM for a Core2 system.  The first thing that seemed off to me was that the RAM registered as 3.25GB of RAM in Windows 7 (64 bit).  Now, I am using PCIe graphics, and I see no graphics aperture settings in the BIOS.  So my first question is, why isn't this memory available?  My motherboard is a DFI LT600-D. 
Now, naturally I wanted to test this used RAM to make sure it is free of errors, so I used MemTest86 to do a scan.  The results were very unusual.  It makes me suspect that MemTest isn't working at all.  The errors column is loaded, and it says "pass: 0  Errors: 9720" and the errors column is growing.  What might I be doing wrong?  (See picture)

[image: Screenshot of MemTest86]

Comment: Make sure memory remapping is *enabled* in the BIOS. Also, reset all memory voltage and timing settings to their defaults (which should be *auto*).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see neither of those options in my BIOS.  It is a full Phoenix AwardBIOS setup so I don't know why they aren't here.

Comment: I know you state that you are using Windows 7 64 bit but are you sure your CPU is actually 64 bit itself and not 32?

Comment: @EricF Yes, my CPU is a Core2 E6600 Duo, definitely 64 bit.

Comment: Ok sorry just checking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like memtest86 is working properly and telling you that you have a faulty memory stick.
All the errors are between 1070.6MB and 1198.6MB (exactly 128MB section), so one stick probably has a failed section in one of its chips. Use memtest86 on each stick individually to find which is faulty. BIOS/Windows has probably noticed faulty section and is ignoring it, so less than 4GB available.
"pass: 0 Errors: 9720" means it has already found 9720 errors and has not yet completed the first pass.

Comment: I'll test each chip and let you know what I find.

Comment: All of the errors were on one card.  Oddly enough, this card is discoloured when compared to the others... it's a brighter green.  I'll be contacting the seller for a replacement.